# Найти декартово произведение множеств, количество которых неизвестно

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Нашел много информации по этой задаче, но так и не смог найти примера ее решения в виде кода на Питоне.
Составил несколько черновиков, до конца их не дописал, просто не знаю как все объединить.
Вот, собственно, и черновики:

```
from itertools import product

def gams_from_pairs(pairs,result):
    result.append(list(product(pairs)))
    return(result)
```

```
from itertools import product

pairs=['Aa','bb','CC','dD']
gams=list(product(pairs))
print(gams)
```

```
from itertools import product

def gams_from_pairs(pairs,result):
    for i in range(len(pairs)):
        result.append(list(product(pairs[i])))
    print(result)
    return(result)


pairs=[['A','a'],['b','b'],['C','C'],['d','D']]
result=[]
```

Нужно решение конкретной задачи: дан массив `pairs` вида `[['Aa'],['bb'],['cC'],['DD']]`. На выходе нужно получить комбинации AbcD, AbCD, abcD, abCD в любом порядке.
Мне нужно решение в виде кода, а там я разберусь что да как, а то я никак не могу понять решение этого типа задач при неизвестном количестве массивов в `pairs`.
Спасибо.

Comment: А вы только часть же перечислили комбинаций? Их так-то должно 16 получиться, если считать повторяющиеся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
from itertools import product

pairs=['Aa','bb','CC','dD']
gams=list([''.join(x) for x in product(*pairs)])
print(gams)
```

`product` принимает последовательности, которые нужно объединять, как *отдельные аргументы*, поэтому нужно развернуть список `pairs` в отдельные аргументы с помощью оператора `*`. В результате получаются кортежи (tuples), которые можно превратить в строки с помощью `string.join`.